# Where is the scaladoc for scala.language.existentials?

Tags: scala, existential-type

When I tried to write a class that accepts any `Class[_]` as a parameter:

```
case class A(klass: Class[_])
```

I got this error:

> test.scala:1: warning: inferred existential type Option[Class[_$1]]
>   forSome { type *$1 }, which cannot be expressed by wildcards,  should
>   be enabled by making the implicit value scala.language.existentials
>   visible. This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import
>   scala.language.existentials' or by setting the compiler option
>   -language:existentials. See the Scala docs for value scala.language.existentials for a discussion why the feature should be
>   explicitly enabled. case class A(klass: Class[*])
>              ^ one warning found

I'm willing to know why it doesn't work. But where is "the Scala docs for value scala.language.existentials"? I googled "scaladoc scala.language.existentials" but got some threads I can't understand.

Clarification: I know the 'correct' way to implement such a class is:

```
case class A[T](klass: Class[T])
```

But I want to know what the warning message means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case what you're looking for is a `ClassTag`:

```
class A[T](implicit val tag : reflect.ClassTag[T])
```

This gives you the `ClassTag` object for the generic parameter that you can use to access the `Class` given when objects are being created.

As for existentials, you can check:

- [Existential types in Scala by Miles Sabin](http://mikeslinn.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/scala-existential-types.html)
- [Haskell documentation about them](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types)
- [Scala types of types](http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/#existential-types)

Comment: I don't get it. My `case class A[T](klass: Class[T])` works fine. What's the advantage of `ClassTag`?

Comment: @LaiYu-Hsuan, if you write `class A[T: ClassTag]` (it is the same thing as in the answer), you can create this class like this: `new A[String]`, not like this: `new A(classOf[String])`, because the compiler will provide you a value of `ClassTag` automatically. It is the idiomatic approach to get runtime class for a type variable. And you always can retrieve `Class[_]` from `ClassTag[T]`.

Answer (score 3):

Heather Miller just explained on scala-user that you use the left-hand pane's search for "language", and then the right-hand pane's search for existential, since the left pane doesn't do members.

If you find a discussion you don't understand, then you know you're in the right place.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and I hit this SO thread; none of the answers are a direct answer to the question, so I'll add it below. The Scala docs for value scala.language.existentials are probably in the JavaDoc comments, which state:

```
 /** Only where enabled, existential types that cannot be expressed as wildcard
   *  types can be written and are allowed in inferred types of values or return
   *  types of methods. Existential types with wildcard type syntax such as `List[_]`,
   *  or `Map[String, _]` are not affected.
   *
   *  '''Why keep the feature?''' Existential types are needed to make sense of Java’s wildcard
   *  types and raw types and the erased types of run-time values.
   *
   *  '''Why control it?''' Having complex existential types in a code base usually makes
   *  application code very brittle, with a tendency to produce type errors with
   *  obscure error messages. Therefore, going overboard with existential types
   *  is generally perceived not to be a good idea. Also, complicated existential types
   *  might be no longer supported in a future simplification of the language.
   *
   *  @group production
   */
  implicit lazy val existentials: existentials = languageFeature.existentials
```